# Unable to specify the DOS path to load a .js file in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I am new mongo db and I created .js file I want to load.
I working on a windows machine and I am trying to specify the full path of the js file in my command but I keep getting errors.

load("C:\Test\test.js")

I did a lot searching and I do not see how to solve this issue.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use \\ instead of \:

```
load("C:\\Test\\test.js")
```